# Alternative to metamask popup

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, metamask, decentralized-applications

so I have created a DApp whose purpose is basically to transfer user details given by user to admin using blockchain. I don't want my users to download metamask and have eth in order to use the DApp. Is there any other alternative where they can use my DApp and I will pay for their transactions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about meta-transactions.

This article should give you a good point of entry:

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/learn/sending-gasless-transactions